# How to partition a very large word list search on distributed machine for quicker answer

Tags: database, hadoop, apache-spark, information-retrieval

This is more an architectural question, how you will solve this problem at scale.

Suppose you have a list of millions of words, and you need to search whether those millions of words exists in a collection of trillions words corpus.

**For example:**

```
Word_List =
["This", "a", "test", "of", "two", "words","what","words"]  

The_corpus =
["This", "a", "test", "of", "two", "words","what","words","blah","blah2"]
```

In above example all words in word_list found in the_corpus, so our function will return true. Note that "words" has to be present twice.

I wonder that we can solve this by Hadoop or Spark by distributing the_corpus on a cluster and writing Mapper and Reducer to check if the word exists in the corpus, but I cannot figure out how word_list will be distributed. I cannot keep word_list on Master node, as it is too big.

Comment: have to be in the same order and without any other words between them?

Comment: @Shiping order is not important.

Comment: sort corpus words, partition across the nodes, remember the boundaries, search words only on nodes where they could be located

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You task has aims similar to common join operation. There are certain thing you can take into consideration while implementing it:

1. You can use [Bloom](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bloom_filter) filter based on **Word_List** to reduce the range of potential values in your **The_corpus** collection
2. For minor collection usually distributed cache is used to make resource available on all the task nodes. In your case this should probably be a great space hit as it will be copied to every node where the actual task will be performed. To improve this you can put your file directly into your file system with some bigger replication factor, 10 for example (depends on the number of nodes in the cluster), in order to increase its availability. Then in your task you will be able to download it directly which will significantly save your space comparing to the Distributed cache approach, but the cost would be your bandwidth in non-local reads. You can play around with this to find the optimal number of replications.

Answer (score 1):

The *word_list* can be distributed across the nodes via the [Hadoop's DistributedCache](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/stable/hadoop-mapreduce-client/hadoop-mapreduce-client-core/MapReduceTutorial.html#DistributedCache) mechanism. In essence, a file(-s) is specified at the initial job configuration phase, which is then physically copied to all the nodes that will run map tasks. Then each map task can access and use the content of this file.

So, your example task is solved in Hadoop in the following way: *word_list* and *corpus* are put into HDFS; in the job *word_list* is set to be spreaded accross all nodes using DistributedCache; at map phase *word_list* is checked against a particular split of *corpus* (i.e. each map task has *word_list* in full and 64/128/...MB split of *corpus*, where 64/128/... is defined by HDFS block size set for *corpus* files); at reduce phase required aggregation happens, e.g. if just True/False should be returned then reducers input might be number of occurrences for all words in *word_list*: if all words have at least one occurence then True, False otherwise.

In general, this kind of tasks is known as **map-side join**. See some example code (with usage of DistributedCache), for example, [here](http://www.myhadoopexamples.com/2014/04/16/hadoop-map-side-join-with-distributed-cache-example/).

Answer (score 0):

You can add both word_list and corpus on hdfs in hadoop that will distribute both the files on all the nodes. Now you can read both the file subsequent from hdfs. In your mapper code you can use filesystem class to access word_list file from hdfs in mapper code.  And you can mention your corpus file in as input file path in Hadoop jar command .

Answer (score 0):

Guess your question is how to speed up the searching using a cluster with corpus partitioned in some way among the cluster nodes. Here I outline what I'd do.

1. sort corpus and remove duplicates but add a number of the duplicates for each word, such as a 1, blah 1, blah2 1, of 1, test 1, this 1, two 1, what 1, words 2, etc., probably one word per line to simplify search process or in some packed form to speed up IO.
2. partition corpus into N parts and record the alphabets range of words in each part, e.g., part 1 has words starting from a to aff, part2 from afg to amp, etc. put all the parts on the shared storage accessible to each node.
3. sort word_list (and remove duplicates but add the count for each word) and divide the words into M groups for M nodes and assign each group to one node for search.
4. do binary search (because the words are sorted) for each word on each node (the search tool knows which corpus part to search based on the alphabets range) and report back as true (if all words are found with right counts) or false (can return as soon as one word fails). Of course it's up to you to decide what's considered a hit. optimization can be done for the search. for example, if one node is assigned the group with three words test, this and two and the word test is found in the middle of part x, the search for the word this will only need to be carried out in the right half of part x.